# How do I prevent incorrect CI build failures when building lots of projects?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, dotnetnuke

How do I fix this incorrect CI build failure? `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1360,9): warning MSB3101: Could not write state file "obj\x86\Debug\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache". The process cannot access the file 'C:\Servers\CruiseControl.NET\Builds\WheelMUDSharp\src\Actions\obj\x86\Debug\ResolveAssemblyReference.cache' because it is being used by another process.`

We have around 170 DotNetNuke modules that all depend on two modules. When the two dependencies change and all projects rebuild we get incorrect failures like the one above. How can we stop from getting these failures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put those project in a single queue - as they all write to the same file, they can't build simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, each project should have its own copy of the code, so multiple projects can build at the same time.  Otherwise, skolima's recommendation on a single queue is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>MSB3101</MSBuildWarningsAsMessages>
    <ProjectGuid>{C27EC026-BEA7-47BB-8422-14EE2F665B4D}</ProjectGuid>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read [answer] to get some useful tips on answering questions. Esp. the part "fuller explanations are better".

Comment: @GertArnold it's too obvious I think (suppress warning). "Fuller explanations are better" is just a guide which supposed to help provide better answers. And in most cases it's true but not in all cases.

Comment: Stack Overflow is mainly about future readers. It may be obvious for you, *maybe* for the asker, not necessarily for all future readers. A small explanation doesn't hurt and may help a lot.